# Returning list which has the highest number on a specific index on a input variable - list of list

Tags: ocaml

Newbie here!
I'm trying to build a program that returns a list that has the highest number on a specific index. I've been trying so many things, and this looks the simplest code I can come with.

On the below example I was expecting the list `["2";"4";"6";"7";"8";"4"]` to be returned. However I came across this error:

```
File "blablabla.ml", line 7, characters 63-74:
Error: This expression has type int but an expression was expected of type 'a list
```

Anybody can help?

```ml
let a = [
  ["1";"2";"3";"4";"5";"6"];
  ["2";"5";"6";"1";"5";"7"];
  ["1";"2";"3";"4";"5";"6"];
  ["2";"4";"6";"7";"8";"4"]
];;

let rec max lista i = match lista with
  | [] -> 0
  | x::xs ->
      let best_list = max xs i in
      if int_of_string (List.nth x i) > int_of_string (List.nth best_list i) then 
        x
      else
        best_list
;;

let result = max a 4;;

result;;
```

**EDIT:**
Still haven't succeeded it, thanks to @G4143 and @glennsl I managed to go with another aproach, but know is complaining with syntax error.

```ml
let max l i = match l with
  | [] -> []
  | x::xs ->
      let rec compare_lists x xs i =
        if i < (List.length xs) then
          if (List.nth x i) > (List.nth xs i) then
            x
          else
            xs
        else
          failwith "Position too large for list"
;;
```

Comment: What is the `if ... else ...` expression supposed to return? A `list` or an `int`?

Comment: a string of list

Comment: And what is `x`?

Comment: a string of list, I believe, as I am iterating through a list of list

Comment: Sorry, `x` isn't the problem. The `0` you return for the empty list is the problem. That makes the turn type of `max` an `int`, which makes `best_list` an `int`, which makes using ~list.nth` on it a problem, because it expects a list.

Comment: That did help with the function! Thanks!
Now, I am getting this error when declaring result:
Exception: Failure "nth".

Comment: That means the index is out of bounds of the list. Which is probably because you've replaced the `0` with an empty list so that `best_list` eventually receives that.

Comment: Thank you for helping out. 
So that means the function `rec max` will eventually run an empty list causing the error?

Comment: Yep, since that's the base case. So you might want to check specifically for a one-element list as well (or instead, if you assume it won't be called with the empty list), and handle that appropriately.

Comment: I understood what you suggested, however if I change the match with expression `[] -> []` , I come back with the same problem as at beginning. Is there any way to return the value `best_list` when it reaches the empty list, while keeping it as a list variable?

Comment: Yeah, just pass it along as a function argument.

Comment: You mean : ``let rec max lista i best_list = 
[]->best_list        ....``?
I've tried to do it, but it keeps giving me incompatible variables errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would approach this problem. Note: I left out the solution for the branch of many lists.

```
let get_max_at_pos l1 l2 pos =
  if (pos < List.length l1) && (pos < List.length l2)
  then
    if (List.nth l1 pos) < (List.nth l2 pos)
    then
      l2
    else
      l1
  else
    failwith "Position too large for list"

let get_max l pos =
  match l with
  | [] -> None
  | hd::[] -> Some hd(*should check position against hd length*)
  | hd1::hd2::[] -> Some (get_max_at_pos hd1 hd2 pos)
  | hd::tl -> (*now you have to solve the branch for many lists*)
```

This is a better and cleaner solution since you have it working now:

```
let a =
  [
    [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6];
    [2; 5; 6; 1; 5; 7];
    [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6];
    [2; 4; 6; 7; 8; 4]
  ]

let get_max_of_pos l1 l2 pos =
  if (pos < List.length l1) && (pos < List.length l2)
  then
    if (List.nth l1 pos) < (List.nth l2 pos)
    then
      l2
    else
      l1
  else
    failwith "List too short"

let get_max l pos =
  match l with
  | [] -> failwith "Empty list of list"
  | hd::tl ->
    List.fold_left (fun a d -> get_max_of_pos a d pos) hd tl

let ans = get_max a 5
```

You can rewrite the fold_left part by hand if you like.

Comment: I've come with:
changed to recursive the function ```get_max``` and  on the last match  did the statement ```let best_player = get_max tl in get_max_at_pos hd best_player```.
I'm not sure if it's right

Comment: You should be able to use Some(List.fold_left (fun a d -> get_max_at_pos a d) hd tl) on the last branch and it'll work. Do you understand how fold_left and fold_right work?

Comment: I don't have too much pratice, but for what I've been reading it passes the result of a argument through the elements of the list from left to right (fold_left). This is a huge help, it seems to work, however it stays with the value -> ```Some [result_best_list]```

Comment: It's sorted, I used another match with to sort it out!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try breaking the problem down into easier steps? How about create a function that takes 2 lists of even length and returns a list with the highest element of both list by position. Something like this.

```
let rec get_max_at_position l1 l2 pos =
  if pos < (List.length l1)
  then
    if (List.nth l1 pos) > (List.nth l2 pos)
    then
      l1
    else
      l2
  else
    failwith "Position too large for list"
```

Comment: I don't think that would work as I will have N lists within a list

Comment: @OmegaSmash Yes that's true but you eventually have to check one list against the next list.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I think I understood what you meant, I edited the post based on your help. I can feel it getting closer ! It's complaining on syntax now

Comment: If you are new to OCaml then you might want to check out this site which is more geared towards discussion: https://discuss.ocaml.org/